# Drupal: Automatically email user 1 month after registration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, email

I'd like to be emailing every user that registers, about a moth after his registration, with additional benefits of his membership.

This is what many media sites do, e.g. ft.com sends you an email message every week, for a period of 5 weeks after your registration:

- Week #1 - ft.com 1/5: Welcome blah blah...
- Week #2 - ft.com 2/5: Make
  the most of your membership...
- ...
- Week #5 - ft.com 5/5: ...

What would be the best way to implement this in Drupal? E.g. is there a module, or should I go custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to go with the rules module (https://drupal.org/project/rules)

Create a new component in rules that checks if a user account was created one month ago, if so, send an email. Then schedule that rule to run every day using the scheduler.

You'll find many helpful tutorials here: https://drupal.org/node/1866108

Probably 1-6, 14, and 16 would help you a lot.

EDIT: As suggested in a comment, it is bad for performance to check every user account every day when you have a large user base, rather schedule directly on user registration.

Comment: I would definitely avoid checking all users every day for possible actions, if the site gets several hundreds or thousands users, it will be unbearable. You can schedule the notification directly on user registration, using rules scheduler. It would look like: when user registers, schedule 1 mail notification in +1 week, another in +2 weeks etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, improved my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task using the `cron job`.There is a `hook` function named `hook_cron()` the suites your purpose mate.In the `hook_cron()` function check the `current date` with the time of registration of the user.If the `difference` in time is equal to the desired time period  using the `drupal_mail` function send your mail to the user with the `desired content`.You can find more about hook_cron in this [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7).You can run the cron job at definite interval using the `contributed module` `poormanscron`.Hope that helps u mate.. :)